# Migrating large Java codebase to using Optional

Tags: java, intellij-idea, migration, option-type, java-11

I work on a quite large Java codebase in Java 11.
The database we work with as a lot of nullable fields so we have to do a lot of null checking by hand, and a lot of times we don't do it properly so we end up having a lot of NPEs.
To avoid this, we wanted to use the Optional type as return value for nullable fields getters.
This does work well and it makes the code a lot more explicit.
However, now we have to change every line of code where we call one of theses getters to add `.get()` or `.orElse(null)`.
I just spend 5 hours trying to do it by hand, but I updated only a fraction of the code base...
How would you proceed to do this migration? Any tools/technique?

I use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate fyi.

Ps: I know that using `.get()` or `.orElse(null)` is pointless, but it's just a first step, that would allow us to write new code cleaner.

TLDR : How would you add `.get()` to every method that return an Optional type in a large codebase ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.openrewrite.org/ it might help you with writing some custom transformation.

Comment: I haven’t used the replace in files feature of Intellij IDEA much recently. Can’t it accept a regular expression? Something like `\.get\w+\(\)` to find calls to getters. Then replace with the same plus whatever you want to append.

Comment: Regex won't cut it.  You need a transform engine that can add your patch, but ONLY if the getter invoked is returning an Optional type.   That means the transform tool has to build symbol tables that the rewrite rule can inspect.

Comment: you can look into IDEA's structural search and replacement https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html

Comment: What would work with almost every IDE: 1) create a new method returning `Optional` (with a different name) 2) change the old method to delegate to the new method and call `orElse(null)` afterwards 3) Tell the IDE to inline the old method to all callers 4) Rename the new method to have the old method’s name. After that, you have code with exactly the same behavior of the old, using `null` for absent values but with an `Optional` based API. Then, you can start changing the callers manually to use `Optional` in a better way (which may take some time but can be done parallel to other things).